# Error when trying to manually update an .aar library/module inside an android project

Tags: android, android-library

I am using a library in .aar format (mylib.aar) 
It is a standalone project that I transformed into a module/library so I can re-use it on different projects.
It is working fine but now I have an updated .aar file.  I want to use the updated mylib.aar into the project but I am having problems updating the the .aar file (mylib.aar)

I tried putting my new updated mylib.aar file inside the lib folder but it says that .

```
Project already contains subproject with the name mylib.aar
```

How do I properly update my library with a new updated version?

Comment: change your Project view from android to Project you will see mylib remove it or add with new name for eg mylib1.aar

Comment: I just right click delete it? Or is there a remove module/library option?

Comment: right click and delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your Project view from **android** to **Project** you will see `mylib` remove it or add with new name for eg `mylib1.aar`

[image]